# Reask for User Entry or Continue the code

Tags: c#, user-input

Facing this problem all the time but couldn't really figure out how to overcome with it;

It is related with the user entry - in case the user enters something wrong I want the program to continue or reask the question;

an example ;

- I want the user to enter the age
- when the user enters the age correctly I want the program to continue (but in below code it asks 5 times
- if the user enters a wrong entry (i.e string) I want the program to reask to enter the age

Vm appreciate to hearing your kind assitance

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            int _Age;
            Console.Write ("Please enter your age :") 
            string AgeEntry = Console.ReadLine();
            bool AgeCheck = Int32.TryParse(AgeEntry, out _Age);
            if (!AgeCheck)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter your age : ");
            }
            else
            {
                i--;
            continue;

            }


        }
```

Comment: Look up the `while` keyword.

Comment: How do you define _user enters a wrong entry_? Is it only for getting an integer or you have an exact number in your mind.

Comment: Based on the Int32.TryParse, I assume OP is looking for an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

infinite loop, just issue a "break;" and it will drop out....

```
    int _Age;

    while( true )
    {

        Console.Write ("Please enter your age :") 
        string AgeEntry = Console.ReadLine();
        bool AgeCheck = Int32.TryParse(AgeEntry, out _Age);

        if ( AgeCheck == true ) {  break; }

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int age = 0;

while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your age:");
    string entry = Console.ReadLine();
    if (int.TryParse(entry, out age)) break;
}
```

The idea is simply to run an "infinite" loop until a valid age is entered, at which point we `break` out of the loop.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of the infinite loops:

```
int age = 0;
do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your age:");
    string entry = Console.ReadLine();
} while (!int.TryParse(entry, out age));
```

Nothing wrong with the infinite loop inherently. I just think it's cleaner without.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your question about the question being asked 5 times.  You have a for loop that will spin through the code 5 times regardless of the answer the user gives.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
{ your code is here }
```

In the code below, after the do loop, you'll have the input from the console in the answer variable and the parsed int in the age variable.  You can create a new console app in VS and paste this into Program.cs and run it to test.

```
using System;

namespace console {
    internal class Program {
        private static void Main( string[] args ) {
            int age;
            string answer;

            do {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.Write( "Please enter your age: " );
                answer = Console.ReadLine();
            } while ( !int.TryParse( answer, out age ) );

            Console.WriteLine( string.Empty );
            Console.WriteLine( "Thanks, let's continue..." );
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```